# How to make cleveref compress different-level theorems?

Tags: cleveref, amsthm

Whenever you have differently deep sections in your document and wish to number your theorems (as well as notes, lemmas, propositions, ...) according to the currently deepest level, you tend to write code such as

```
\documentclass[USenglish]{lipics-v2018}%%% loads amsthm and changes it a bit. Available from https://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publications/lipics/instructions-for-authors/
%\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsthm}%%% Same outcome up to formatting
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thmS}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{thmSS}{Theorem}[subsection]
\newtheorem{thmSSS}{Theorem}[subsubsection]
\crefname{thmS}{Thm.}{Thms.}%%% to be used on the section level
\crefname{thmSS}{Thm.}{Thms.}%%% to be used on the subsection level
\crefname{thmSSS}{Thm.}{Thms.}%%% to be used on the subsubsection level
%%% Similar junk for noteS, noteSS, noteSSS, lemmaS, lemmaSS, lemmaSSS, propS, propSS, propSSS, etc.
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\begin{thmS}\label{thm:in1}
  My great theorem.
\end{thmS}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\begin{thmSS}\label{thm:in21}
  Another great theorem.
\end{thmSS}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3.1}
\subsubsection{Subsection 3.1.1}
\begin{thmSSS}\label{thm:in311}
  One more great theorem.
\end{thmSSS}
\section{Section 4}
The following result follows from \cref{thm:in1,thm:in21,thm:in311}: \dots
\end{document}
```

(Above, I'm primarily interested in the `lipics` class from https://www.dagstuhl.de/en/publications/lipics/instructions-for-authors/, but the same question also applies to the combination `article`+`amsthm`.)
The output is great:

[image: output of pdflatex]

(An aside: once could say that an alternative way to achieve the same output would be defining `\Crefname` rather than `\crefname` and using the `capitalize` class option for `cleveref`. My question does not apply to this alternative, since for `enumi`, for example, I wish to have both capital and noncapital versions: `\crefname{enumi}{part}{parts} \Crefname{enumi}{Part}{Parts}`.)

There is just one issue: the space in the last line of the output is a bit wasted, since you could express the same information with a shorter

> The following result follows from Thms. 1.1, 2.1.1, and 3.1.1.1: ...

How to make `\cref{...}` produce such an output automatically? Can one write some other macro (say, `\magiccref{...}`) doing this kind of automation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't actually think a separate theorem environment for every depth is the right way to go about this, even if you're not using `cleveref`. It would be more effective to instead define just a single theorem environment and make the formatting of the theorem number depend on the current depth.

The following code produces the same output, except for the fact that `cleveref` now regonises that these are all theorem environments of the same type (because they are). It therefore prints "Thms." instead of repeating "Thm." three times.

```
%\documentclass[USenglish]{lipics-v2018} %% <- also works
\documentclass{article}

%% Redefined these to leave out any zeros
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection\ifnum\value{subsection}>0.\arabic{subsection}\fi}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection\ifnum\value{subsubsection}>0.\arabic{subsubsection}\fi}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsubsection]
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.}

\begin{document} %% I only replaced thmS, thmSS and thmSSS by thm below
\section{Section 1}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:in1}
  My great theorem.
\end{thm}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:in21}
  Another great theorem.
\end{thm}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3.1}
\subsubsection{Subsection 3.1.1}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:in311}
  One more great theorem.
\end{thm}
\section{Section 4}
The following result follows from \cref{thm:in1,thm:in21,thm:in311}: \dots
\end{document}
```

*(The output below was created by uncommenting the `lipics-v2018` line, but it works with `article` and `amsthm` as well.)*

[image: Output]

### Explanation:

I've defined just a single theorem-like environment called `thm`, whose numbering is subordinate to that of `subsubsection`s.
This means that the `thm` counter will be reset automatically to 0 whenever the `section`, `subsection` *or* `subsubsection` counter is either incremented or are reset to 0. (Incrementing the `section` counter — generally achieved by a `\section` directive — resets the `subsection` counter and hence also the `subsubsection` counter to 0 automatically. Likewise, a `\subsection` directive resets the `subsubsection` counter to 0 automatically.)

The formatting of the number assigned to a `thm` environment is determined by the macro `\thethm`. This macro is defined as

```
\thesubsubsection.\arabic{thm}
```

since we run the instruction `\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsubsection]`. So it takes the formatted `subsubsection` counter and affixes a period and the current value of the `thm` counter, expressed in arabic numerals.

The macro `\thesubsubsection` determines the formatting of the number assigned to a `subsubsection`-level header. In many document classes, including both `article` and `lipics-v2018`, `\thesubsubsection` is defined by default as

```
\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}
```

The macro `\thesubsection`, in turn, is defined by default as `\thesection.\arabic{subsection}`, and `\thesection` generally just expands to `\arabic{section}`.

What the two `\renewcommand` instructions above do is redefine `\thesubsection` and `\thesubsubsection` so that they affix `.\arabic{subsection}` and `.\arabic{subsubsection}` only if these counters have a positive value.
The result will be that all zeros in the formatted `thm` numbers are suppressed, both when they're stated and when they're cross-referenced, say, via a `\cref` instruction.

This method also lets you change formatted `equation` numbers in the same way, by adding `\numberwithin{equation}{subsubsection}` to your preamble. (`\numberwithin` is provided by the `amsmath` package.)

---

---

## New addendum

Here is a version that adapts to earlier redefinitions of `\thesubsection` and `\thesubsubsection`. 
Below, `\thesubsection` is redefined to check the value of the relevant counter and use either `\thesection` (if it is zero) or the original definition of `\thesubsection` (if it is non-zero). The new definition of `\thesubsubsection` works the same way.

I redefined section numbering to look like `1:1a` instead of `1.1.1` for demonstration purposes.

```
%\documentclass[USenglish]{lipics-v2018} %% <- also works
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[subsubsection]
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.}

%% Prior redefinition of \thesubsection and \thesubsubsection:
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\thesection:\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection{\thesubsection\alph{subsubsection}}

%% Redefine \thesubsection and \thesubsubsection to omit counters with value 0:
\edef\thesubsection{%                          %% <- edef to expand \thesubsection (once)
  \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\value{subsection}=0 %% <-if subsubsection=0
    \noexpand\thesection                       %% <- use \thesection
  \noexpand\else                               %% <- otherwise
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\thesubsection}%   %% <- use whatever \thesubsection was before
  \noexpand\fi
}
\edef\thesubsubsection{%
  \noexpand\ifnum\noexpand\value{subsubsection}=0
    \noexpand\thesubsection
  \noexpand\else
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\thesubsubsection}%
  \noexpand\fi
}

\begin{document} %% I only replaced thmS, thmSS and thmSSS by thm below

\section{Section 1}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:in1}
My great theorem.
\end{thm}
\section{Section 2}
\subsection{Subsection 2.1}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:in21}
Another great theorem.
\end{thm}
\section{Section 3}
\subsection{Subsection 3.1}
\subsubsection{Subsection 3.1.1}
\begin{thm}\label{thm:in311}
One more great theorem.
\end{thm}
\section{Section 4}
The following result follows from \cref{thm:in1,thm:in21,thm:in311}: \dots

\end{document}
```

---

---

### Older addendum.

You could accomplish the same thing by redefining `\thethm` instead of `\thesubsection` and `\thesubsubsection`.
You should then insert

```
\renewcommand\thethm{\thesection
   \ifnum\value{subsection}>0.\arabic{subsection}\fi
   \ifnum\value{subsubsection}>0.\arabic{subsubsection}\fi
   .\arabic{thm}}
```

after the `\newtheorem` line, and remove the two other `\renewcommand` lines in the code block at the top. You could then do the same thing for `\theequation`.
There is little benefit to doing it this way, unless the fact that `\thesubsubsection` prints zeros when you are not in a subsubsection is somehow relevant to you.

Comment: +1 for showing how to set up `thm`, `note`, `prop`, and other theorem-like environments (and, if so desired, `equation` environments as well!) with "numbers" whose formats vary automatically with the sectioning depth.

Comment: I've take the liberty of eding your explanations a bit, mainly to provide additional information about what some of the example code does. Feel free to revert.

Comment: @mico No problem, I think these are all improvements. I had quite deliberately used the parenthesised word "(effectively)" though because the actual definitions of `\thethm` etc. use `\@arabic{\c@...}` instead of `\arabic{...}` and I didn't want to claim something that is technically incorrect. (So I will reinsert that.)

Comment: @mico On second thought, I'll leave it as it is. Being clear is probably more important than not being "technically wrong". I am going to change your `--` into a proper em-dash though.

Comment: @user49915 - The only notable "unexpected" effect caused by the dynamic redefinition of `\thesubsubsection` might arise if a given `\section` contains `\subsubsection` directives but no `\subsection` directives. However, skipping a level of sectioning headers is a typographic no-no; your document shouldn't have such issues to begin with. (If it does such issues, you should tackle them ASAP.)

Comment: @user4915 Did you manage to rename all of your theorems?

Comment: @user49915: Glad to hear. I've added a version that adapts to earlier redefinitions of `\thesubsection` etc.